# How to iterate map containing set in c++?

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, iteration

I have a map containing a set of integers like this:

```
std::map<int, std::set<int>> haha;
```

but the number of elements in each set is unknown. Now I want to iterate the whole map and print the key and values to a file `"f"`. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (std::map<int, std::set<int> >::const_iterator i = haha.begin(); i != haha.end(); ++i) {
    int key = i->first;
    const std::set<int>& values = i->second;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But for the set of integers, you just copied it, I want to fprintf them all indeed.

Comment: @yobichi , so? Loop on that set and output values. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebc3934df30e596b

Answer (score 2):

The most concise way(s) I know of (let me know if not):

```
for(auto const& pair : haha)
{
    std::cout << pair.first << " : ";
    std::copy(pair.second.begin(), pair.second.end(), std::ostream_iterator(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

or entirely with range-for loops:

```
for(auto const& pair : haha)
{
    std::cout << pair.first << " : ";

    for(auto x : pair.second)
        std::cout << x << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

And if you want to print it to a file, just create `std::ofstream` and replace `std::cout` with its name, since this is C++, not C. We don't want to see `fprintf`s in this nice code.

Comment: @LogicStuff Thanks a lot. But for the first way, is it difficult if I want to fprintf it?

Comment: @LogicStuff my bad I missed that for loop

Comment: @yobichi If what you want is indeed "print to a file" instead of "call `fprintf()`," you could open a `std::ofstream` and do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (auto mapitr = haha.begin(); itr != haha.end(); ++mapitr) {
   std::cout << mapitr->first << std::endl;
   for (auto setItem: mapitr->second) {
     std::cout << setitem << std::endl;
   }
}
```